# Tensorflow bulk image classification

Tags: tensorflow

I have few questions about TensorFlow. I'm following the "TensorFlow for Poets" tutorial (https://petewarden.com/2016/02/28/tensorflow-for-poets/), and i got the expected result.
However i would like to know two thing:
1. How to classify more than one image at a time?
2. How to extract the result in .txt format?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue, so I built [the TensorPy GitHub repo](https://github.com/TensorPy/TensorPy) to easily handle image classifications of either individual or multiple images directly from web pages. How it works: For multiple images, first it scrapes all the image links directly from a web page given. Then it downloads those images to a temporary folder and converts those images to JPEG format. Finally, it uses TensorFlow to classify all those images and print out the result, which you can then easily output to a txt file by adding " > output.txt" to the end of your command line run statement. See the video tutorial link in the repo, and swap out the individual image file from the example for a web page. Since you probably want your own customization, feel free to look at how the code works so that you can create your own version as you need it.

After creating my solution, I saw that there are also other good solutions available online. Check out [Siraj's image classification tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QfNvhPx5Px8), which has a link to the associated GitHub repo in the video description.

UPDATE:
If you're just looking to run TensorFlow's classify_image.py on multiple image files in a folder, you can easily create a bash script for that:

```
   for i in temp_image_folder/*.jpg; do
   python classify_image.py --image=$i
   done
```

Comment: Hi Michael, 
could you point me in the right direction where i can classify bulk image from a folder in my system and not from a link?

Comment: and how do i train the machine with new images?

Comment: Create a .sh file to loop through all images in a folder and run the script:

Comment: for i in temp/*.jpg; do
  python classify_image.py --image=$i
done

Comment: `
    for i in temp/*.jpg; do
    python classify_image.py --image=$i
    done
`

Comment: That uses: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/models/image/imagenet/classify_image.py

Comment: Training is a bit more complicated. Find a good tutorial online! (I've not mastered that yet)

Comment: I can't seem to edit the comments, but that looping script is 3 lines of code.

Comment: Cool... Thank you for all the help. I will try this and reach out to you for any more information/help again. Can you please try to add the looping script in the comments again?

Comment: It's been added to the answer above.

Comment: can you point me in the right direction for training a new model and how do i use it?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QfNvhPx5Px8 - "Build a TensorFlow Image Classifier in 5 Min "

Comment: im sorry but could you make it a bit simpler for me? are there any python scripts where i can change the folder path an call for training since im using oracle virtual box and not a docker? the video talks about how to use docker. How do it use a python script to train a new mode with  my own set of images and link it to classify test images?

Answer (score 0):

I am currently using the "find" command.

```
find ./ -type f -iname "*.jpg" -exec python3 classify_image.py --image={} \;
```

But I'm also looking for a solution that does not have to load the complete script for every image.