# How to train a set of images (apart form the tutorial) and use it to classify in Tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow

I am using from the TensorPy GitHub repo (built by Michael Mintz) (https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/models/image/imagenet/classify_image.py)to easily handle image classifications of either individual or multiple images directly from web pages. However i want to train the system with my own set of images and then run the classifier. Could anyone please point me in the right direction for training a new model and how do i use it in classifying a set of bulk images?

Thank you.

Comment: how do i use the trained data set to classify new images? is there any way to link both? (Classifying Code from https://github.com/TensorPy/TensorPy and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40135244/tensorflow-bulk-image-classification?answertab=votes#tab-top)

Comment: You'll find a script called `imagenet_eval` in the same directory.

Comment: im getting this error

Comment: shri@shri-VirtualBox:~/Desktop/Test/inception_test/models/inception/inception$ python imagenet_eval.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "imagenet_eval.py", line 30, in <module>
    from inception import inception_eval
ImportError: No module named inception